# loopback installation failed in windows 10 "fatal error LNK1181 libeay32.lib"

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback, apiconnect

Trying to install loopback & apiconnect lead me to this error..can anyone help to clear out this

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\OpenSSL-Win64\lib\libeay32.lib' [C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\
npm\node_modules\apiconnect\node_modules\ursa\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
```

i am installing from this path:https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Installation.html

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSL lib names changes, I wrote up a workaround here: [Can't install loopback cli](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-cli/issues/69#issuecomment-495814642)

Basically you install Win64 OpenSSL and create a symlink to the new file where expected.

> C:\OpenSSL-Win64\lib>mklink .\libeay32.lib "C:\Program
>   Files\OpenSSL-Win64\lib\libcrypto.lib" 
>  symbolic link created for
>   .\libeay32.lib <<===>> C:\Program
>   'Files\OpenSSL-Win64\lib\libcrypto.lib'

After that, the package should install without error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install compiler tools ? Please follow the instructions [here](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Installing-compiler-tools.html)

Or just skip reading and try these :

1. Run Powershell as an administrator
2. `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`

Then install loopback & apiconnect

Also you can refer to this [issue](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/2385).